# Word frequency database with senses

Tags: nlp, cpu-word, word-frequency

I am looking for a downloadable database of word frequencies/probabilities including their senses. Ideally, if it was mapped with WordNet.

In the list, some words would be listed multiple times if they have multiple senses e.g. frequency for 'bank' as an institution would be greater than river 'bank'.

Other datasets showing frequencies by word/part of speech would be helpful too.

Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 1):

N gram Frequencies are available in Google Ngram data. Although this does not answer the wordnet or the "senses" part of the question, it is a good start.

Use [this](https://pypi.org/project/google-ngram-downloader/) package for experimenting the same